# Spectral norm of lower triangular perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, perturbation-theory

Suppose $A\in R^{n×n}$ is a matrix equal to sum of the Identity matrix and a lower triangular matrix $L$.
\begin{equation}
A=I+L
\end{equation}
All diagonal entries of $L$ are equal to $0$, so that, all diagonal entries of $A$ are equal to $1$.

Define spectral norm (or the largest singular value) of a matrix $X\in R^{n×n}$ as
\begin{equation}
\|X\|=sup_{\|v\|_{\ell_2}=1}\|Xv\|_{\ell_2}.
\end{equation}
Suppose $|\|A\|−1|<\epsilon$. What can I say about $\|L\|$? Is there an upper bound on $\|L\|$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

Comment: You have that $L=A-I$ and so $\lVert L \rVert \le \lVert A \rVert +1< 2+\epsilon$.

Comment: Well that is rather obvious. I am looking for a less trivial bound which approaches $0$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out though. I should mention that another trivial bound is $\epsilon\sqrt{n}$ however I need a bound independent of $n$ if possible.